# What's a "photopolymer holographic diffuser"?

Tags: lighting, lighting-modifiers

I saw a mention of [photopolymer hologhraphic diffuser](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuser_(optics)#Photopolymer_based_diffuser) which piqued my curiosity.  But I can't find anything useful via Google.

Does anybody know what that is.

Answer (score 2):

A holographic diffuser uses holograms to achieve better control over the diffusion compared with simple diffusive materials like ground glass, most importantly it [reduces backscatter](http://silver.neep.wisc.edu/~lakes/HoDifLoScat.pdf) (less light is reflected backwards).

Holograms are usually made by embossing specific very small-scale patterns on a material which have the desired effect on incoming light.

And photopolymers are materials which change their characteristics when they are exposed to light. This can be used to give them specific shapes, such as in some kinds of 3D printers - but also to produce holograms.

So the "photo" in photopolymer interestingly refers to the way they are machined, not on their effect on light, which is in this case the desired end result.